# What is the use of JSONB[] (JSONB ARRAY) data type in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am using the Postgres database in one of the projects. Now I have a requirement to store JSON array in a database. Something like below:

For e.g., I have below JSON structure:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "XYZ"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "ABC"
  }
]
```

For this purpose, I am using JSONB datatype and it works fine. Then what it is the use of JSONB[] datatype when we can simply store a JSON array in JSONB datatype?

Comment: `jsonb[]` is not an "extra" datatype, it's simply an array of JSONB values. Similar to `text[]` or `integer[]`. You can create arrays from every type. But I do agree that using an array `jsonb` hardly ever makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion you are doing it correctly.

The `jsonb[]` datatype stores multiple `jsonb` objects in a PostgreSQL array.

In your case you can access all the array elements using the `jsonb` functions and operators.

If you decomposed that array into its constituent objects and stored each as an element in `jsonb[]`, then you would need to use a mix of PostgreSQL array functions and operators and `jsonb` functions and operators to act on the data's contents.