# Inserting array of jsonb objects into postgresql table column

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I have a table with two columns `application` and `projects`. While `application` is a simple column of `varchar` type, `projects` should hold array of `jsonb` objects.

A sample record is:

```
application | projects
-----------------------
App1        | [{"project": "project1", "url":"url1"},{"project": "project2", "url": "url2"}]
```

Now there is a json file which holds the data to be inserted into this table programmatically in the exact same structure as this table which needs to be read through Node.js and inserted into the table.

My question is how do I write an insert query which inserts the projects field correctly into the table. I am a beginner in Postgresql and unaware of the function that can do this. I want to write something like this:

```
Insert into <tablename> values('App1', 
some_function_that_converts_string_to_jsonb_array('[{"project": "project1", "url":"url1"},
{"project": "project2", "url": "url2"}]');
```

What function of Postgresql can achieve this? I have tried using `jsonb_build_array` but it is not working.

Thanks!

EDIT:

The value of the `projects` column should be that I can query on it.

Comment: It should work with just the string representation of the JSON:  `. . . values ('App1', '[1, 2, 3]')`

Comment: I tried it. It is throwing error. ``"[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.``. The type of projects column is ``jsonb[]``

Comment: Querying can be done, but the syntax will be verbose.  Inserting a new project will be problematic.  If you are in the planning stages, then you should use a normalized schema to simplify those expected future operations.  This is the classic case of "pay me now or pay me later."  Taking the json shortcut with the one-time, up-front data modeling means you will pay dearly on every query, insert, or update you write in the future.

Comment: I still say to use a normalized schema, but to get past your error about "explicitly-specified array dimensions', change the type of the `projects` column to `jsonb`.  Please see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62917486/13808319

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to insert a JSON as a string into a postgres table column of the type jsonb?

Then this is your query:

```
INSERT INTO <YOUR_TABLE>(projects) VALUES ('[{"project": "project1", "url":"url1"},{"project": "project2", "url": "url2"}]')
```

You can query the results using the methods described here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html

You can add the JSON as an array object with this query:

```
INSERT INTO <YOUR TABLE>(projects) VALUES (array['[{"project": "project1", "url":"url1"},{"project": "project2", "url": "url2"}]'::JSONB])
```

Comment: No, the type of column is ``jsonb[ ]``. The column should hold array of jsonb objects

Comment: sorry did not ready properly. I added the insert array as second query. But I can tell you working with json array objects is gonna be pretty painful...

Comment: What should be the better approach then. I am a very novice to Postgresql

Comment: You should normalize your table properly. Take the effort and unpackage your json in javascript and insert all values in proper tables and columns. e.g make a project table with an id, name, url etc... Especially if you want to query the data in the json often. The JSON approach seems fast at first but it's gonna get pretty annoying because u have to write complex querys for the simplest things.

Comment: So you want to say that I make another project table having application as foreign key and then perform a join query on both tables?

Comment: yes exactly. There are some use case were JSON / XML can make sense but this isn't one.